# get value from xml with r by attribute

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I'm trying to get values from `xml` that looks like this:

```
<data>
    <result name="r">
        <item>
            <str name="id">123</str>
            <str name="xxx">aaa</str>
        </item>
        <item>
            <str name="id">456</str>
            <str name="xxx">aaa</str>
        </item>
    </result>
</data>
```

So far, I can get the `id` value in the following way:

```
xmlfile <- xmlParse(url)
data <- xmlRoot(xmlfile) 
result <- xmltop[["result"]]
for (i in xmlSize(result)) {
  print(xmlValue(result[[i]][[1]]))
}
```

This seems highly inefficient and only works if "id" is stored in the first child element. So, is there a way to get the value of an element (`123, 456`) by searching for the attribute (`name`) and value (`id`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `xml2` package is very good for solving this type of problem.

```
library(xml2)
page<-read_xml('<data>
    <result name="r">
               <item>
               <str name="id">123</str>
               <str name="xxx">aaa</str>
               </item>
               <item>
               <str name="id">456</str>
               <str name="xxx">aaa</str>
               </item>
               </result>
               </data>')

#find all str nodes
 nodes<-xml_find_all(page, ".//str")
#filter out the nodes where the attribute name=id
 nodes<-nodes[xml_attr(nodes, "name")=="id"]
#get values (as character strings)
 xml_text(nodes)
```

**Update**

Using Xpath selectors everything can be accomplished in 1 line

```
#R verison >4.0
xml_find_all(page, ".//str[@name='id']") |> xml_text()
```

Here is a link to a handy xpath path cheat sheet:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/xpath-css-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/