# How to eliminate data while retaining specific items

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to clean up the output from an ECG in order to further analyze heart rate variability. Specifically, I need to remove everything from the text file EXCEPT the numbers between the word "start" so the only thing that is left is one column of numbers.

Here is an example of what the output looks like:

```
<EMSE_Event_List>
<bSaveNotation>0</bSaveNotation>
<sQID></sQID>
<bUseQID>1</bUseQID>
<Event><Name>[seg]</Name><Start>0</Start><Stop>0</Stop>  
<Status>1</Status><Color>255</Color><Attribute>0</Attribute>  
<TimeStart>0</TimeStart><TimeStop>0</TimeStop>  
<FreqStart>0</FreqStart><FreqStop>0</FreqStop>  
<FWHM_Time>0</FWHM_Time><FWHM_Freq>0</FWHM_Freq></Event>
<Event><Name>R</Name><Start>186</Start><Stop>186</Stop>  
<Status>2</Status><Color>255</Color><Attribute>0</Attribute>  
<TimeStart>0</TimeStart><TimeStop>0</TimeStop> 
<FreqStart>0</FreqStart><FreqStop>0</FreqStop>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in standard xml format. The best way to handle this is to use a XML parser tool.  `XML` and `xml2` are two popular packages/libraries.  I prefer using the `xml2` library.
With a XML parser, it is easy to pull out the values from the only requested nodes and without using complicated Regular Expression syntax.

```
text<-"<EMSE_Event_List>
<bSaveNotation>0</bSaveNotation>
<sQID></sQID>
<bUseQID>1</bUseQID>
<Event><Name>[seg]</Name><Start>0</Start><Stop>0</Stop>  
<Status>1</Status><Color>255</Color><Attribute>0</Attribute>  
<TimeStart>0</TimeStart><TimeStop>0</TimeStop>  
<FreqStart>0</FreqStart><FreqStop>0</FreqStop>  
<FWHM_Time>0</FWHM_Time><FWHM_Freq>0</FWHM_Freq></Event>
<Event><Name>R</Name><Start>186</Start><Stop>186</Stop> 
<Status>2</Status><Color>255</Color><Attribute>0</Attribute> 
<TimeStart>0</TimeStart><TimeStop>0</TimeStop> 
<FreqStart>0</FreqStart><FreqStop>0</FreqStop></Event></EMSE_Event_List>"

library(xml2)
page<-read_xml(text)
values<-xml_text(xml_find_all(page, "//Start"))
values<-as.numeric(values)
values

[1]   0 186
```

See this question for another example: [get value from xml with r by attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45256789/get-value-from-xml-with-r-by-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

With the `stringr` library:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(text,"(?<=<Start>)[0-9]+(?=</Start>)")

[[1]]
[1] "0"   "186"
```

But `xml2` should work fine also

Answer (score -1):

A R-base solution

```
s <- "<EMSE_Event_List>
<bSaveNotation>0</bSaveNotation>
<sQID></sQID>
<bUseQID>1</bUseQID>
<Event><Name>[seg]</Name><Start>0</Start><Stop>0</Stop> . 
<Status>1</Status><Color>255</Color><Attribute>0</Attribute> . 
<TimeStart>0</TimeStart><TimeStop>0</TimeStop> . 
<FreqStart>0</FreqStart><FreqStop>0</FreqStop> . 
<FWHM_Time>0</FWHM_Time><FWHM_Freq>0</FWHM_Freq></Event>
<Event><Name>R</Name><Start>186</Start><Stop>186</Stop> . 
<Status>2</Status><Color>255</Color><Attribute>0</Attribute> . 
<TimeStart>0</TimeStart><TimeStop>0</TimeStop> 
<FreqStart>0</FreqStart><FreqStop>0</FreqStop>"

start <- unlist(gregexpr(pattern ="<Start>",s)) + 7
end <- unlist(gregexpr(pattern ="</Start>",s)) - 1
unname(mapply(substr, x=s, start=start, stop=end))  
[1] "0"   "186"
```

The offsets to start added/subtracted to start resp. end are added to not include the matched strings.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use regular expression for this.

```
library(stringr)
x<-'`<EMSE_Event_List>
<bSaveNotation>0</bSaveNotation>
<sQID></sQID>
<bUseQID>1</bUseQID>
<Event><Name>[seg]</Name><Start>0</Start><Stop>0</Stop> . 
<Status>1</Status><Color>255</Color><Attribute>0</Attribute> . 
<TimeStart>0</TimeStart><TimeStop>0</TimeStop> . 
<FreqStart>0</FreqStart><FreqStop>0</FreqStop> . 
<FWHM_Time>0</FWHM_Time><FWHM_Freq>0</FWHM_Freq></Event>
<Event><Name>R</Name><Start>186</Start><Stop>186</Stop> . 
<Status>2</Status><Color>255</Color><Attribute>0</Attribute> . 
<TimeStart>0</TimeStart><TimeStop>0</TimeStop> 
<FreqStart>0</FreqStart><FreqStop>0</FreqStop>'

x<-str_extract_all(x,"<Start>[0-9]+</Start>")
y<-data.frame(heartbeat=as.numeric(str_extract_all(x,"[0-9]+")[[1]]))
y
      heartbeat
1         0
2       186
```